# Can I use LASSO as a variable selector with only three variable?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, lasso

Can we still use LASSO even when we have a small number of variables?

Comment: Why do you want to do variable selection? What do you want to achieve with your model?

Comment: I want to remove redundant predictors?

Comment: Is the principle of LASSO the same with 30 predictors and 300 predictors and 3 predictors and 3000 predictors?

Comment: With 3 variables it is easy to do a best subset selection. It is in theory much better than LASSO, unless you also need parameter shrinkage.

Comment: @user30609 What I meant to ask is whether you want to make inference about the relationship between the covariates and the outcome, or whether you are interested in making predictions.

Comment: @SimonBogeBrant both........................................................